# nvl condition - checking with many values for org_id parameter

Tags: oracle

The condition I have is :

```
nvl(GECM_ICP_PKG.GECM_GET_PARAMETER_VALUE_FNC('GECM_SCX_VALIDATION','REN_SCX_VALIDATION',v_org_name,NULL,NULL),'N') = 'Y'

SELECT nvl(GECM_ICP_PKG.GECM_GET_PARAMETER_VALUE_FNC('GECM_SCX_VALIDATION','REN_SCX_VALIDATION',v_org_name,NULL,NULL),'N') FROM DUAL;
```

Here my requirement is to pass values from `org_id` column of `ap_supplier_sites_all` table as `v_org_name` parameter.

like for loop, I want to check for all the org_id's without checking by passing each `org_id` in `v_org_name` parameter.

Comment: You might want to consider using [coalesce](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) instead of `nvl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM ap_supplier_sites_all
 WHERE NVL (GECM_ICP_PKG.GECM_GET_PARAMETER_VALUE_FNC ('GECM_SCX_VALIDATION',
                                                       'REN_SCX_VALIDATION',
                                                       org_id,
                                                       NULL,
                                                       NULL),
            'N') = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Include that table/column into your query, such as

```
SELECT org_id,
       NVL (GECM_ICP_PKG.GECM_GET_PARAMETER_VALUE_FNC 
             ('GECM_SCX_VALIDATION',
              'REN_SCX_VALIDATION',
               org_id,                       --> this
               NULL,
             NULL),
            'N')
  FROM ap_supplier_sites_all;                --> this
```